# Nightwatch this.api out side of a custom function results in undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

Using `Nightwatch 1.5.1`
I'm trying to declare my `this.api` in a variable at the top of the `Object Page` like this `const browser = this.api` but when I use it in a custom command I get an error.

**Example - Doesn't Work**

```
const browser = this.api;
module.exports = {
    elements: {}
    commands: [{
       someFunction(element){
            browser.useCss();
            browser.waitForElementVisible(element);
            browser.click(element);
       }
    }]
}
```

Results in an error `Cannot read property 'useCss' of undefined`

**Example - Works**

```
let browser;
module.exports = {
    elements: {}
    commands: [{
       someFunction(element){
            browser = this.api;          // Works
            // cosnt browser = this.api; // Works
            browser.useCss();
            browser.waitForElementVisible(element);
            browser.click(element);
       }
    }]
}
```

All I want is to NOT assign my `this.api` every time I write a function.

Thanks!